# How to obtain component instance in a function that is passed in as parameter?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using [angular-resizable-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element) and the view expects a `validateResize` function to be passed in. My current code looks like following:

```
<div mwlResizable
     [enableGhostResize]="true"
     [validateResize]="validate"
     <!-- Other stuff -->
</div>
```

And the component:

```
@Component({
  // Stuff
})
export class TdeComponent {

  // Other code

  validate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {

    if (event.rectangle.width < 50 ||  event.rectangle.height < 50)
      return false;

    // I need the component instance here.
    // However, `this` keyword refers to the caller, not to the component

    return true;
  }
}
```

Validate is passed in as a parameter. When it is called, `this` doesn't reference my component, it references the caller class. However, I need component variables inside this method. How can I access component reference inside `validate` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions

```
validate = (event: RedizeEvent) => {
    // code
}
```

Or bind context `[validateResize]="validate.bind(this)"`

Comment: I tried out your solution, it's working. Here is your solutions in a StackBlitz with different method names, but same functionality. Interestingly, using .bind(this) is working but shows the wrong result. Huh? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-efdlxy

Comment: he shows `Hello John!`,is this the wrong answer?

Comment: Funny! I was fooling myself, sorry, it's alright, because John is the right answer, not the wrong one :) Sorry, it's being too late....